# Get Plural Label in specific language

Tags: apex, describesobject, localization

So I can do something like

```
Id myId = '999999999999999';
String objectPluralLabel = myId.getSobjectType().getDescribe().getLabelPlural();
```

This returns the plural label of the object in the current user's language.

Is there any way to get the object's plural label in a specific language or even to just get the master label?

This isn't in the context of a visualforce page so I can't just set the language at the page level.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Stil no answers ?